# Present as Maclaurin series the function $f(x)=\ln\left(\pi\sqrt{\frac{2+x}{2-x}}\right)+\arctan{\frac{1-x}{1+x}}$ and find the radius of convergence

Tags: calculus, power-series, taylor-expansion

I need to present the function $f(x)=\ln\left(\pi\sqrt{\frac{2+x}{2-x}}\right)+\arctan{\frac{1-x}{1+x}}$ as a Maclaurin series.

I really have no idea about this one. Attempts such as$$f(x)=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}{\frac{(-1)^k{\left(-1+\pi\sqrt{\frac{2+x}{2-x}}\right)}^{k+1}}{k+1}}+\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}{\frac{(-1)^k\left(\frac{1-x}{1+x}\right)^{2k+1}}{2k+1}}$$don't really work. First of all, I'm not sure this is correct, and even if it is, finding the radius of convergence of such expressions seems like an impossible task. Could someone tell me if the following Maclaurin expansion is correct and how to find its radius of convergence, please?

Comment: I would first note the domain of $f$ is $(-2,2)$. I would also note for $x\in (-1,1)$ that $$\arctan\Big(\frac{1-x}{1+x}\Big)=\arctan(1)-\arctan(x)$$ You can also break up the natural logarithm using properties of logs. These manipulations make the function less formidable when you proceed to develop their MacLaurin series representations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you define $\require{cancel}f_1(x)=\log\left(\pi\sqrt{\frac{2-x}{2+x}}\right)$ and $f_2(x)=\arctan\left(\frac{1-x}{1+x}\right)$, then $f=f_1+f_2$.

Now, note that\begin{align}f_1(x)&=\log\pi+\log\sqrt{\frac{2-x}{2+x}}\\&=\log\pi+\frac12\left(\log(2-x)-\log(2+x)\right)\\&=\log\pi+\frac12\left(\cancel{\log2}+\log\left(1-\frac x2\right)-\left(\cancel{\log2}+\log\left(1+\frac x2\right)\right)\right)\\&=\log\pi+\frac12\log\left(1-\frac x2\right)-\frac12\log\left(1+\frac x2\right).\end{align}But the Maclaurin series of $\log\left(1-\frac x2\right)$ and of $\log\left(1+\frac x2\right)$ are easy to compute: they are equal to$$-\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{x^n}{n2^n}\quad\text{and to}\quad\sum_{n=1}^\infty(-1)^{n-1}\frac{x^n}{n2^n}$$respectively. So, the Maclaurin series of $f_1$ is$$\log\pi-\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{x^{2n-1}}{(2n-1)2^{2n-2}}\left(=\log\pi-\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{x^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)4^n}\right),\tag1$$whose radius of convergence is $2$.

On the other hand,$$f_2'(x)=-\frac1{1+x^2}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty(-1)^{n+1}x^{2n},$$(when, and only when, $|x|<1$) and therefore, since $f_2(0)=\arctan1=\frac\pi4$,$$f_2(x)=\frac\pi4+\sum_{n=0}^\infty(-1)^{n+1}\frac{x^{2n+1}}{2n+1}.\tag2$$So, the Maclaurin series of $f$ is the sum of the series $(1)$ and $(2)$ and its radius of convergence is $1(=\min\{1,2\})$.

Comment: Thank you! You explained it briefly yet very clearly. You were very helpful.

Comment: I'm glad I could help.